# Divide mysql query to fit divs

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry if the title is a bit confusing, I tried my best!

So basically I have **4 column** divs that each contains **5 links** for example. The links come from a table in my database, so new links are added and some others deleted, hence why I need to do it via database instead of writing it by hand. Now my issue is to divide the array in order to show 5 links per column (so when 5 links have been placed, div is closed and a new one is opened, unless there is no more link.

for example:

```
<div class="column">
  <a href="">Link</a>
  <a href="">Link</a>
  <a href="">Link</a>
  <a href="">Link</a>
  <a href="">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <a href="">Link</a>
  <a href="">Link</a>
  <a href="">Link</a>
  <a href="">Link</a>
  <a href="">Link</a>
</div>
```

etc.

Thanks to anyone!

Comment: Show some code, what you've got so far.

Comment: Don't mix query logic with presentation. Iterate through the results to present your data.

Answer (score 5):

The PHP function [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/array_chunk) is nice to distribute an array of links into columns:

```
$columns = array_chunk($rows, 5);

foreach ($columns as $links)
{
    echo '<div class="column">', "\n";
    foreach ($links as $link)
        printf("<a href=\"%s\">Link</a>", $link);
    echo '</div>', "\n";
}
```

I don't know your column names nor how you query the database, so I don't have any array indexes here written out. But I think you'll get the idea.

Comment: Thanks alot, I definately understand what you're trying to show. I'll give it a try right now aswell as the others and see what performs best. Thanks alot for your reply

Answer (score 0):

How about using the modulo operator

```
<div class="column">
for ($i = 0; $i < $nRow; $i++) {
  if ($i % 5 == 0 && $i) {
    echo '</div><div class="column">';
  }
  echo "<a href='{$links[$i]}'>Link</a>";
}
</div>
```

Comment: @hakre: good catch that's the prob when you write code without testing

Comment: As I said to hakre, thanks alot for the reply, really appreciated. Ill give a try to both examples and see what works best